# Delete _new table from pt-online-schema-change

Tags: mysql, percona-toolkit

I used pt-online-schema-change but the process died in the middle.

The script makes a copy of the original table with the name followed by "_new".

Since the process died in the middle, the table "_new" wasn't deleted and when I try to delete it my application crashes.

It seems whenever I alter the original table this _new table is also changed so if it is not found it crashes.

I would like to know how can I remove this _new table.

Comment: As you can see in the documentation (https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html), pt-online-schema-change creates trigger to do the magic of a "lockless" schema change. If this process crashed, you might have to delete the triggers yourself and then the table from a mysql command prompt.

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to know the name of the magic. Now that you indicated that it was a `trigger` I was able to find them and kill them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like many other solutions designed for an almost lockless schema change, pt-online-schema-change works by creating triggers on your table and creating a _new table. As stated in the [documentation](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html):

> Any modifications to data in the original tables during the copy will
>   be reflected in the new table, because the tool creates triggers on
>   the original table to update the corresponding rows in the new table

If this utility crashed, you might have to do the cleanup yourself. This might include:

- Removing the triggers: have a look at the [SHOW TRIGGERS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-triggers.html)  syntax to see the ones pt-online-schema-change has just created;
- Delete the _new table.

Comment: When I try to re-run pt-online-schema-change, the error says "tablespace `_mytable_new` exists". However, when I view all the tables, this underscore-prepended table is nowhere to be found, and thus can't be deleted. Where do I find it?